# Getting /data/data/my.app/files path programmatically?

Tags: android

In my app, I've just successfully downloaded a file and I opened it like this:

```
OutputStream output = openFileOutput("myfile.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

With a little browsing, I've found my file in `/data/data/my.app.namespace/files/myfile.txt`. I don't want to hardcode the path but later on in my app I'm going to want to access myfile.txt and I want to dynamically get that folder path. I've tried most of the folders in the `Environment` object like `Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` but that only returns `/data`. Where can I look to get where private files go? Or is it safe to assume that this structure won't change? I don't like hardcoding it, but it would work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do it by using `context.getFilesDir() + "/filename.ext"`