# get file from /data/data/my.app/files path in android programmatically

Tags: android, xml

I create a xml file in this path /data/data/my.app/files/new.xml with below code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


                FileOutputStream fileos = null;
                try{
                    fileos = openFileOutput("new.xml", MODE_PRIVATE);

                }catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    Log.e("FileNotFoundException",e.toString());
                }
                XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
                try{
                serializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");
                serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
                serializer.startTag(null, "root");
                serializer.startTag(null, "Child1");
                serializer.endTag(null, "Child1");
                serializer.startTag(null, "Child2");
                serializer.attribute(null, "attribute", "value");
                serializer.endTag(null, "Child2");
                serializer.startTag(null, "Child3");
                serializer.text("Some text inside child 3");
                serializer.endTag(null,"Child3");
                serializer.endTag(null,"root");
                serializer.endDocument();
                serializer.flush();
                fileos.close();

                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Exception","Exception occured in wroting");
                }

            }
}
```

Now i want send this file with socket but i don't know how access to the file path programmatically.
I've tried most of the folders in the Environment object like Environment.getDataDirectory().getAbsolutePath() but that only returns /data.
How can i access to this path and read my xml file?

Exactly i see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596926/getting-data-data-my-app-files-path-programmatically) link but i can't find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a reference to your private folder, you should use this method:
[getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir())

Moreover, you have to declare this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: explain! details please!

Comment: i use this methods getFileStreamPath(),  getFilesDir (), getDir() but doesn't work, i just want get file path and read it:(

Comment: Great, but **what** doesn't work? Is there an error?

Comment: with all this methods i have a different error... sometimes change type or anythings.. i don't know what happened

Comment: So, **what** is the error when you try  `getFilesDir()`